# Typescript does not recognize that the generic parameters match

Tags: typescript, design-patterns, type-constraints

In the following code typescript complains that the argument does not match the called function.

In general that is ok, but in this case the type of `emailType` and `args` are bound to the same generic type `T` so it should not error.
As you can see in the following lines, if you fix the type T to some concrete value, e.g. `"Foo"` typescript correctly recognizes that the types match.

- Is there either a way to tell typescript that the types match (without a `as any` assertion)?
- Do you know of a better pattern to this problem? I really like it, because it makes calling `sendMail` convenient as you have intellisense for the emailType, which makes it easy to see which emails are available, and then intellisense for the required data to send the email.

```js
const mails = {
  Foo: (args: { foo: string }) => "",
  Bar: (args: { bar: string }) => "",
}

function sendMail<T extends keyof typeof mails>(emailType: T, args: Parameters<typeof mails[T]>[0]){
  mails[emailType](args) // ERROR: Argument of type '{ foo: string; } | { bar: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ foo: string; } & { bar: string; }'
  mails[emailType as "Foo"](args as Parameters<typeof mails["Foo"]>[0]) // works
  mails[emailType as "Bar"](args as Parameters<typeof mails["Bar"]>[0]) // works
}
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70652329/get-return-type-of-class-method-via-method-name-in-typescript/70653102#70653102) answer is probably a duplicate. Let me know if it is

Comment: Yes, i think the problem is the same. I guess type assertion is the only solution as typescript does the type intersection before checking the argument to function combination (which makes sense in most situations). Still, i think it should be possible for typescript to understand that only correct combinations of function to arguments are possible in this case...
Anyway thanks again @captain-yossarian for your help :)

Comment: you can do smth like [this](https://typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.6.0-dev.20220115#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgQwJYBsItsplay.dev/mpvXbw) but there is still an error